# Guard : phpunit is not installed on your machine

Tags: tdd, laravel-4, phpunit, guard

I use `Guard` for my Continuous Testing.

My Guardfile is

```
guard :phpunit2, :all_on_start => false, :tests_path => 'app/tests/', :cli => '--colors -c phpunit.xml' do
    # Run any test in app/tests upon save.
    watch(%r{^.+Test\.php$})

    # When a view file is updated, run tests.
    # Tip: you probably only want to run your integration tests.
    watch(%r{app/views/.+\.php}) { Dir.glob('app/tests/**/*.php') }

    # When a file is edited, try to run its associated test.
    # Save app/models/User.php, and it will run app/tests/models/UserTest.php
    watch(%r{^app/(.+)/(.+)\.php$}) { |m| "app/tests/#{m[1]}/#{m[2]}Test.php"}
end
```

I install phpunit since composer `"phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"`

But when i use guard :

```
ERROR - phpunit is not installed on your machine.
```

My CLI for to use phpunit is `vendor/bin/phpunit`

So, i try to add in Guardfile this `:command => "vendor/bin/phpunit"` in the guard config

The complete config :

```
guard :phpunit2, :all_on_start => false, :tests_path => 'app/tests/', :command => "vendor/bin/phpunit", :cli => '--colors -c phpunit.xml' do
```

but, i have always errors

```
ERROR - phpunit is not installed on your machine.
```

How do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have have:

```
gem install guard-phpunit
```

installed?

Take a look at this: https://github.com/Maher4Ever/guard-phpunit

Comment: Yes and i use bundler : http://bundler.io/ however i d'ont use `guar-phpunit` but `guard-phpunit2` beacause phpunit2 it's recently update